# Tracking user on the server-side in Google Analytics after payment on third party site

Tags: google-analytics, google-api-php-client

I have an e-commerce website using Google Analytics ([async ga.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/)) on which the payment is done on a third-party service (by a French bank) that does not allow cookies on their site. So, when my customer goes off-site to pay and complete the transaction, I lose her in Google analytics. Of course she may click on the "go back to website" link but this is not 100%, far from it.

However the banking site will send a server-to-server confirmation of the transaction result (payment completed or not), along with many variables. Among the variables is a text field that is returned unchanged from the original request emanating from our our server.

To rephrase: I can send a text field (of 3200 characters max) along with  the POST request to the banking server at the time the user clicks the payment button (this is a POST HTML form) and they will transmit back this text unchanged to my server (but we are no longer in a browser).

So given these parameters how can I send the signal to Google Analytics that the visitor has completed the transaction (if she has) ?
Are there better/simpler ways to accomplish this?

The environment is LAMP and I can use the [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/).

Comment: I don't think the GA API is meant to send trackPageview-Calls (you are looking rather for something like https://code.google.com/p/php-ga/). It would be easier if the payment processor could redirect your user back to your page (GA has parameter that retains the original source even after a detour via a third party page)

Comment: Hi Eike, thanks for the reply. I'm aware of https://code.google.com/p/php-ga/ but I have not tried it yet. I am worried that this third party library might not evolve with Google or that Google might ban its use at some point. However it does seem to be able to do what I want. Now I still don't know exactly how to retrieve the relevant GA session information that I'd have to pass it. Any pointers?

Comment: In theory ? Read utm Cookies, post values to remote server, receive values back, call utm.gif on the google server with the cookie values.   However I'm not aware of any up-to-date libraries that parse the google cookies for information (shouldn't be too hard to roll yourself). This website: http://utmgifparser.appspot.com/ might help to understand the structure of the utm.gif - instead using php-ga you could construct the gif url and send it via curl.

Answer (score 0):

You can create unique User ID for each user:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en

and then you can use google Measurement protocol with the data you need along side with the user id:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference
Sending a hit using s2s pixel

that way you'll have a special User ID views - showing which users exactly finished the transaction and all the other values you added to the hit (utm_campaign for example).